# Removing minimum no of edges to disconnect two vertices in a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, discrete-mathematics

Here I am trying to disconnect two vertices in a graph with minimum edge removal possible.

[image: example graph]
In this graph between two vertices **A** and **Z** you can find the answer in many ways. In optimal way you can remove just one edge from **A** to **B**.

If there is any specific algorithm for this?

I found some suggestions to solve this by using maximum flow min cut problem but I am not getting general idea to convert this problem into max flow min cut theorem. Also in the process I might end up removing an edge between **F** and **G** which is useless.

Comment: As you state it, this is exactly min-cut: Remove the minimum number of edges to fragment the graph.Since min-cut is dual to max-flow, any algorithm for solving one also solves the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved using Max Flow - Min Cut problem.

You can model your graph into network flow as follows:
1. Consider `A` to be the source vertex, `Z` to be the sink vertex.
2. Set the capacity of each edge to be 1 unit.

Now, solve the Max Flow - Min Cut problem in above network. With it you will be able to find number of edge-disjoint paths from `A` to `Z`. For every such path, remove the first edge (edge originating from source `A`).

**Proof**:
Observe that after removing above edges, you won't be able to reach `A` to `Z`. If you had a path, then Max flow algorithm would have included this path in set of edge-disjoint-paths.
Also, by construction of network, you can't remove lesser number of edges to disconnect `A` from `Z`